# Why doesn't fit_transform work in this sklearn Pipeline example?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I an new to sklearn Pipeline and following a sample code. I saw in other examples that we can do `pipeline.fit_transform(train_X)`, so I tried the same thing on the pipeline here `pipeline.fit_transform(X)`, but it gave me an error

"    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)

TypeError: fit() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)"

If I remove the svm part and defined the pipeline as `pipeline = Pipeline([("features", combined_features)])`, I still saw the error.

Does anyone know why `fit_transform` doesn't work here?

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest

iris = load_iris()

X, y = iris.data, iris.target

# This dataset is way to high-dimensional. Better do PCA:
pca = PCA(n_components=2)

# Maybe some original features where good, too?
selection = SelectKBest(k=1)

# Build estimator from PCA and Univariate selection:

combined_features = FeatureUnion([("pca", pca), ("univ_select", selection)])

# Use combined features to transform dataset:
X_features = combined_features.fit(X, y).transform(X)

svm = SVC(kernel="linear")

# Do grid search over k, n_components and C:

pipeline = Pipeline([("features", combined_features), ("svm", svm)])

param_grid = dict(features__pca__n_components=[1, 2, 3],
                  features__univ_select__k=[1, 2],
                  svm__C=[0.1, 1, 10])

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, verbose=10)
grid_search.fit(X, y)
print(grid_search.best_estimator_)
```

Comment: In the examples I see they always provide also some parameters to `GridSearchCV`. Maybe those are the ones missing?

Comment: In which line does this exception occur?

Comment: it occurred if I run `pipeline.fit_transform(X)` after `pipeline = Pipeline([("features", combined_features), ("svm", svm)])`

Comment: seems that `fit_transform` needs another parameter

Answer (score 0):

You get an error in the above example because you also need to pass the labels to your pipeline. You should be calling `pipeline.fit_transform(X,y)`. The last step in your `pipeline` is a classifier, `SVC` and the [`fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit) method of a classifier also requires the labels as a mandatory argument. The `fit` method of all classifiers also require labels because the classification algorithms use these labels to train the weights in your classifier.

Similarly, even if you remove the `SVC`, you still get an error because the [`fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.fit) method of `SelectKBest` class also requires both `X` and `y`.